# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'request'

Tags: python, django

A silly question: why do we get `TypeError` on the `super`'s `__init__` only? Aren't they supposed to take the same arguments?

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

If it's the same method of the same `forms.ModelForm` class, why does the first one accept `request` and the second doesn't?

Here's `ModelForm`'s `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                 empty_permitted=False, instance=None, use_required_attribute=None,
                 renderer=None):
```

So when I'm calling `form = MyModelForm(request=request)` why does the `MyModelForm`'s `__init__` let it through?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> why do we get TypeError on the super's **init** only? Aren't they
> supposed to take the same arguments?

No, they are not.

When you are creating your ModelForm class, its constructor's signature is `def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)`, so there is not any keywords, just `**kwargs` that allows any number of keyword arguments to be passed while creating the instance of the `MyModelForm` class.

The second function signature is coming from the django `ModelForm` class, which has limited number of keyword arguments, and only those keyword arguments are accepted. You can try passing some random kwargs, like `foo='bar'`, it will again throw error.

```py
def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, auto_id='id_%s', prefix=None,
                 initial=None, error_class=ErrorList, label_suffix=None,
                 empty_permitted=False, instance=None, use_required_attribute=None,
                 renderer=None):
```

But if it also had `**kwargs` in the end, then it'd also accept any keyword arguments.